# How to convert Spring WebClient Response to ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webclient, spring-webclient

I'm able to return ResponseEntity using toEntity() method like below:

```
@GetMapping("/uri")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Data[]>> methodName() {
    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri("http://localhost:8088/externalService")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(Data[].class);
}
```

But I want to process response headers before returning.
The above code converts WebClient response to ResponseEntity and returns immediately but I want to store it in a ResponseEntity variable, process it, and then return the ResponseEntity back.

I referred this -> [Spring WebClient Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#retrieve--)

WHen I tried to store it in a varibale, I get this error -> "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Reactor's `map` operator to modify the headers:

```
return webClient
        .get()
        .uri("http://localhost:8088/externalService")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .toEntity(Data[].class)
        .map(responseEntity ->  responseEntity.getHeaders().add("header", "header-value");
```

Alternatively, you can use `.handle` operator in order to provide response processing:

```java
.handle((responseEntity, sink) -> {
        if(!isValid(responseEntity)){
            sink.error(new InvalidResponseException());
        } else if (isOk(responseEntity))
            sink.next(responseEntity);
        }
        else {
            //just ignore element
        }
    })
```

Comment: I want to do something like the below.

`ResponseEntity<Data> responseEntity = webClient
            .get()
            .uri("http://localhost:8088/externalService")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(Data[].class);`

Check something in ResponseEntity and return it.
If I assign it to a variable, I get this error -> "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3"

Comment: @HarishankarBhatR what do you mean '"check something? "

Comment: Validate response headers etc. To do that, I need to get the response entity from WebClient response.

Comment: @HarishankarBhatR edit made

Comment: In this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#retrieve--), WebClient Response is assigned to this variable: Mono<ResponseEntity<Person>> entityMono .
But from Mono<ResponseEntity<Person>> entityMono, I need to take the ResponseEntity object. If I do entityMono.block() I get the error "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3"

Comment: Have you tried my recommendations?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But I need the response entity object in a separate variable.

Comment: You can't just extract the response without blocking the thread. I show you the correct way to extract and process the response entity in reactive manner.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Starter Web dependency was missing in my pom.xml. Found it and added it back.
Now able to get WebClient response in ResponseEntity format.